# Name some techniques similar to Random Forests

Tags: machine-learning, references, ensemble-learning

I'm interested in what techniques are out there that are similar to, but not the same as, Random Forests. Either for classification or regression or both. Particularly interested in techniques which apply:

1. Random resampling from the data
2. Some form of variable selection / regularisation.
3. Combination of many weak learners.

Bonus kudos for techniques which aren't tree based.

Answer (score 1):

[Random ferns](http://vision.cse.psu.edu/seminars/talks/2009/random_tff/ForestsAndFernsTalk.pdf) and [EnsembleSVM](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~claesenm/ensemblesvm/) might be interesting to you. Both are for classification only. Random ferns has a nice Bayesian philosophy, while ensemble SVM uses SVM base models based on small subsamples. The latter may appear slightly unorthodox since SVM models are not considered weak learners, but the technique works well nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Random forest are based on [Bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) and use can use and learner with them.
There is also the entire family of [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) algorithms, leveraging weak classifiers.